# Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints on opening camera

Tags: ios, layout, constraints, snapshot

**I have a app which use a webview to show some HTML forms. In HTML forms there is added functionality to choose image from device. All functionality is from HTML form for capturing image. When i click on browse button of form from webview camera opens and everything is working fine but i get below log in xcode.**

```
Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x16fa21f0 UIView:0x180afaa0.height == 0.454545*CAMModeDial:0x16f06760.height - 4.09091>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x18065020 CAMShutterButton:0x180bfbc0.centerY == CAMBottomBar:0x16f06100.centerY>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x18065b70 V:[CAMShutterButton:0x180bfbc0]-(0)-[CAMModeDial:0x16f06760]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x18065ba0 CAMModeDial:0x16f06760.bottom == UIButton:0x180b5870'Cancel'.top>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x180645f0 V:[UIButton:0x180b5870'Cancel']-(31)-|   (Names: '|':CAMBottomBar:0x16f06100 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x180b6870 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[PLImagePickerCameraView:0x170f2600(0)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x180b8780 CAMBottomBar:0x16f06100.height == PLImagePickerCameraView:0x170f2600.height>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x16fa21f0 UIView:0x180afaa0.height == 0.454545*CAMModeDial:0x16f06760.height - 4.09091>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.

Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x18065020 CAMShutterButton:0x180bfbc0.centerY == CAMBottomBar:0x16f06100.centerY>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x18065b70 V:[CAMShutterButton:0x180bfbc0]-(0)-[CAMModeDial:0x16f06760]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x18065ba0 CAMModeDial:0x16f06760.bottom == UIButton:0x180b5870'Cancel'.top>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x180645f0 V:[UIButton:0x180b5870'Cancel']-(31)-|   (Names: '|':CAMBottomBar:0x16f06100 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x180b6870 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[PLImagePickerCameraView:0x170f2600(0)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x180b8780 CAMBottomBar:0x16f06100.height == PLImagePickerCameraView:0x170f2600.height>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x18065b70 V:[CAMShutterButton:0x180bfbc0]-(0)-[CAMModeDial:0x16f06760]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

**I am not able to solve it can somebody help me understand these errors and and suggest how to go about solving them?**

**Edit** :- On searching net about **CAMShutterButton,CAMModeDial,CAMBottomBar,PLImagePickerCameraView** i found **CAMShutterButton.h,CAMModeDial.h,CAMBottomBar.h** are class files in **CameraKit.framework** and **PLImagePickerCameraView.h** is a class file in **PhotoLibrary.framework**. Which are part of iOS 8 private framework but i am not using any one of them in my application.

Comment: I've the same, identical and bad issue. and don't know where and how to find a solution. Did you get some help?

Comment: No i didnt got any solution yet @marconline

Answer (score 1):

Change the priority of the constraint

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x18065b70 V:[CAMShutterButton:0x180bfbc0]-(0)-[CAMModeDial:0x16f06760]>" from Required(1000) to High(750)
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but i have no viewcontroller or button with "CAMShutterButton". As mentioned it is logged when i click on browse button to browse device images or to use camera functionality from a html form. @dev

Comment: are you using any third party library?

Comment: No i am not using any third party library. I am simply using a webview for showing html form and rest functionality of taking and adding image into form is not handled by me.

Comment: Camera functionality is by default with HTML form page. I am not opening camera programmatically.